# Incorrect value printed by the 'pow' function in C

Tags: c

Why does the below code gives 127 as output, when it has to be 128. i have even tried to figure out, but I don't understand why 127?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
signed char ch;

int size,bits;

size = sizeof(ch);

bits = size * 8;
printf("totals bits is : %d\n",bits);

printf("Range is : %u\n", (char)(pow((double)2, (double)(7))));

}
```

Comment: Because `char` can only describe values between `CHAR_MIN` and `CHAR_MAX` (defined in `<limits.h>`), and on your system they happen to be -128 and 127, respectively.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the verbatim output.

Comment: You can use `unsigned char ch = 1 << 7;`. Per definition, `1 << n` is the same as 2^n. `pow` is a floating-point function and therefore unsuitable in general.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `128` as result then typecast `pow()` result as `int` instead of `char`. for e.g

```
printf("Range is : %u\n", (int)(pow((double)2, (double)(7)))); /* this print 128 */
```

Why this

```
printf("Range is : %u\n", (char)(pow((double)2, (double)(7))));
```

prints `127` as `pow((double)2,(double)7)` is `128` but at same time that whole result vale **explicitly type cast**ed as `char` and default `char` is `signed` which ranges from `-128 to +127` , hence it prints `127`.

**Side note**, `pow()` is floating point function as @lundin suggested & same you can find [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pow.3.html). you can use

```
unsigned char ch = 1 << 7;
```

to get the same in particular case.

Comment: We see the result described the OP more often due to a bad `pow` implementation returning a value slightly less than the mathematical result, resulting in integer truncation. A C implementation that produces 127 as the result of casting `128` to `char` is less common.